# I would like to get sum from two tables from SQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have following tables I would like to calculate remaining stock.

Table1 inventory in.

```
id    inventory name  quantity in
 1     Dress               10
 2     Shoes               20
 3     Jacket              15
 4     Dress               25
 5     Shoes               35
```

Table 2 inventory out

```
id     inventory name    quantity out
 1      Dress              1
 2      Shoes              1
 3      Dress              1
 4      Shoes              1
 5      Dress              1
```

I want a Query which show following results

```
inventory name    quantity in    quantity out   remaining stock
Dress                 35              3             32
shoes                 55              2             53
jacket                15              0             15
```

Comment: Read up on UNION and conditional aggregation. BTW Probably too late but in my view only 1 table with a column indicating direction is less bother than 2 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next query can be used in your case:

```
SELECT 
    -- select results from two joined tables
    inventory_in.inventory_name,
    quantity_in,
    COALESCE(quantity_out, 0) quantity_out,
    quantity_in - COALESCE(quantity_out, 0) remaining_stock
FROM (
    -- get inventory_name & quantity_in
    SELECT inventory_name, SUM(quantity_in) quantity_in FROM inventory_in
) inventory_in
LEFT JOIN (
    -- get inventory_name & quantity_out
    SELECT inventory_name, SUM(quantity_out) quantity_out FROM inventory_out
) inventory_out 
    -- join two tables by inventory_name
    ON inventory_out.inventory_name = inventory_in.inventory_name;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for query, But I have to add GROUP BY inventory_name then results will be okay.